# Does Lock performance has correlation with the number of its clones

Tags: rust, locking

I have a variable `t: Arc<RwLock<Handle>>` to write/read in the main thread, and in multiple other threads (number of threads = `n`), `t` is cloned only for releasing resource before the program should panic (i.e. `t` would not be called when the program is running
Ok).

In this case, would writing/reading `t` in the main thread be less performant as `n` becomes larger? E.g. is the overhead of attempting to write `t` heavier when `n = 100`, compared with `n = 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are cloning an `Arc` which is conceptually separate from the `RwLock` that it contains (the lock does not know that its being shared). If the clones in the other threads are not *accessing* for the lock, then there's no impact on the lock regardless of how many `Arc`s are.